# How to solve this error Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response working on postman

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1, jwt, cross-origin-read-blocking

I have called third party API using Jquery AJAX. I am getting following error in console

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://example.com/assets/front/font/fonts.min.css with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Comment: The question is about CORB, not CORS

Answer (score 0):

add to your code PHP

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

make sure to place it on top declaration of the header